# authenticate() Always Returns None

Tags: python, django, authentication

- Python 3
- Django 1.5

I've successfully created a user with `create_user()`, and the user can log into the admin section. BUT, making code in my views.py so the user can log in anywhere else, isn't working. Here's the code I'm using, and even when the username & password are definitely correct, `authenticate()` still returns `None`.

```
def dologin(request):
    usrnym = request.POST['usrnym']
    psswrd = request.POST['usrpass']
    usr = authenticate(user=usrnym,password=psswrd)
    if usr is not None:
        if usr.is_active:
            login(request, usr)
            # redirect to success page
        else:
            pass
            # redirect to a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # return an 'invalid login' error message
        errmsg = "Invalid login. Password and username did not match."
        template = loader.get_template('fsr/loginform.html')
        context = RequestContext(request, {
            'title': "Login Page",
            'error': errmsg,
            'usr': usrnym,
            'pwd': psswrd,
            'usra': usr,
        })
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but isn't it supposed to be?

`usr = authenticate(username=usrnym,password=psswrd)`

Comment: Duh! I hate asking stupid questions like this. My brain's fried the past day or so. Django's got my head spinnin'. Thanks! It works now.

Comment: No worries. It always helps when you can have an extra pair of eyes take a look at your code.

Answer (score 2):

it should be username not user its a syntax error

```
usr = authenticate(username = usrnym, password = psswrd)
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I totally missed that detail and I've scoured over this code for the past 2 hours. Sorry I didn't mark your comment as the answer, I didn't see it 'til after I saw the other one.