# django rest framework authenticate keep returning NONE

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework

authenticate keep returning none even I'm sure from the name and the password in database and I write them right . I also check these questions, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557196/authenticate-always-returns-none?rq=3) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778061/authenticate-function-not-working-django-contrib-auth) but didn't help .
here is my code .
views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def user_login(request):
    print("im in login")
    print(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.data.get('name')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        print("username : ",name,"password : ",password)
        user = authenticate(username=name, password=password)
        print("user : ",user)
        if user is not None:
            # Authentication successful
            login(request, user)
            return Response({'message': 'Login successful'})

        else:
            # Authentication failed
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'})

    else:
        # Render the login form
        return   Response({'message': 'Invalid request method'})
```

serializer.py :

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = user_auth.objects.create(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        name=validated_data['name'],
        password = make_password(validated_data['password'])
    )
    return user
```

models.py

```
class user_auth(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

here is the hashed password in database

[image]
I don't know what I did wrong .

Comment: Please post actual formatted code and not pictures of text

Comment: you need to store password in hasH format in User Model

Comment: @Mahammadhusain kadiwala I try both I did store hash password in serializer , but when I tried to authenticate didn't work so I said maybe I should try without hash didn't work either

Comment: Did you consider the salt when hashing the password? It should be the same salt that the app uses. So be careful when you manually add a user to the database or don't add a user directly to the database and use the existing methods.

Comment: Problem is the storing of the password. It should not store it it as a plain string. Did you override the `make_password` function? Did you modify the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in your settings.py? Explanation: `authenticate` will first hash your password input and will then compare the hash-output to your database entry. In your database entry though is the plain, not hashed, password stored. Therefore django thinks it does not match. **Question:** Did you enter the user "ahm" to your database via django, or did you enter the user manually directly to the database?

Comment: @Tarquinius I insert it via django , I will edit my question and add an example of an hashed password ,

Comment: @Amrez I didn't manually add a user to database , I used the api to add it .

Comment: Why not just use Django's included `User` / auth system?- You can extend the model if you need more fields. All the work is already done, no real point of re-doing it

Comment: @Nealium I don't know what u exactly mean , if you talking about the serializer I just follow one stackoverflow answer that why i redefine email and name but password i had to do it to make it hash, the problem is not there , the problem in authenticate i tried everything but always none I tried hash password and not hash , I even tried to authenticate only by username and still got none I must be missing something .

Comment: @the_yaz2000 No, I mean there's already a `User` model included inside of Django `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
..it comes prebuilt with a `create_user`, a signin page, a signup page, password reset, etc. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/    
-You can instead extend from this base, instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work , here is what I changed .
first I added this line to the settings if you didn't add it authenticate by defaul will try to search for the user in auth_user and not in your custom user :

```
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.user_auth'` (change base by the name of your app).
```

Second thing I had to change model by inherits from AbstractUser and not model.Model (and I also add username field and unicod function even tho i don't thing they are so much necessary ):

```
class user_auth(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username.
```

For view and serializer didn't change anything.

Comment: Fun fact: `AbstractUser` inherits from the `User` class, so you don’t even need the email and password fields! It’s already in it! Aka, you’re extending the User model. I wish you luck! Remember to come back in a week and mark this as your answer.